# GNU SED generating 0 byte file

Tags: windows, shell, c#-4.0, sed, gnu

I am executing sed.exe through C# code, by launching a command prompt through c#.

In that, I am dynamically creating the find and replace commands for n number of find and replace pairs.

I have placed sed(windows) binaries in the bin folder of my parent application.

But, this sed is creating 0 byte destination file after executing from above command prompt(through c#), But when same command is executed through command prompt, by navigating to the \bin folder of the parent application, it creates the proper file with the result as replaced data.

Why sed is showing such behavior?

My command for execution is :

```
repl  -e "s~SingleCard~CalculateSF~g"   -e "s~Freight~Shipping~g"   -e "s~CSISrno~PSISrno~g"   -e "s~2BD330B6~drakulla\~\~\~~g"   < "\\myserver\Reports\sample.txt" > "\\Myserver\Reports\result.txt"
```

Comment: How are you calling the command from C#? Are you waiting for the command to complete?

Comment: command = command + "< " + @"""" + sourceFilePath + @"""" + " > " + @"""" + destinationFilePath + @"""";

                parameter = @"sed " + command;
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(parameter);
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (SET PARAMETERS=ReturnCode=1) ELSE (SET PARAMETERS=ReturnCode=0)");
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("SET PARAMETERS");                
                process.StandardInput.Close();

Answer (score 1):

The file isn't ready immediately after writing the command to the process.

Call `process.WaitForExit()` to make your program wait until the process has completed. Then you can read the file.